# Access Denied error while retrieving SSP user?

Tags: 2007, shared-service-provider

I am getting 401 Access denied error while getting userprofile info. I am running below code in the Web Services. Web Service application Identity is the SharePoint System Account.

```
private void UpdateUserInUserProfiles(Customer c, string personalSiteUrl, string siteCollectionUrl)
{
   SPSite mySites = null;
   SPWeb userPersonalSite = null;
   try
   {
      // SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
      //{
           using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteCollectionUrl))
           {
              using(SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb() )
              {
                  Office.ServerContext serverContext = Office.ServerContext.GetContext(spSite);
                  UserProfileManager pmManager = new UserProfileManager(serverContext);
                  string strUserName = _providerName + c.CustomerNumber;
                  HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
                  if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                  {
                     if (context.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] == null)
                         context.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] = spSite.RootWeb;
                     if (context.Items["Microsoft.Office.ServerContext"] == null)
                          context.Items["Microsoft.Office.ServerContext"] = serverContext;
                   }
                   if (!pmManager.UserExists(strUserName))
                   {
                        UserProfile newUser1 = pmManager.CreateUserProfile(strUserName);
                        UserProfile newUser = pmManager.GetUserProfile(strUserName);
                        newUser["PreferredName"].Value = c.FullName;
                        newUser["FirstName"].Value = c.FirstName;
                        newUser["LastName"].Value = c.LastName;
                        newUser["WorkEmail"].Value = c.Email;
                        newUser.Commit();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       UserProfile updateUser = pmManager.GetUserProfile(strUserName);
                       updateUser["PreferredName"].Value = c.FullName;
                       updateUser["FirstName"].Value = c.FirstName;
                       updateUser["LastName"].Value = c.LastName;
                       updateUser["WorkEmail"].Value = c.Email;
                       updateUser.Commit();
                     }                           
                 }

               }
                //});
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                _errorCount = _errorCount + 1;
                _sbErrors.Append(GetErrorMessage(ex));
                LogMessage("Exception Occured in UpdateUserInUserProfiles: " + GetErrorMessage(ex), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (userPersonalSite != null)
                {
                    userPersonalSite.Close();
                }

                if (mySites != null)
                {
                    mySites.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

**Exception That I am getting is :**

```
Message: Exception Occured in UpdateUserInUserProfiles: Thread was being aborted. STACKTRACE :   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtilityInternal.SendResponse(HttpResponse response, Int32 code, String strBody)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtilityInternal.Send401(HttpResponse response)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.SendAccessDeniedHeader(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.EnsureAuthentication(SPWeb web)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileGlobal.GetCurrentUserName()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager.get_strCurrentAccountName()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager.UserExists(String strAccountName)
   at SharePoint.Webservices.SharePointCustomerManagement.UpdateUserInUserProfiles(Customer c, String personalSiteUrl, String siteCollectionUrl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this a web service running outside sharepoint? or is it deployed to sharepoint? Can you tell me why you have those hacks regarding the HttpContext in your code, that shouldn't be necessary?

I have kinda forgotten how it works in 2007, but in the SSP's profile permissions you can grant an account permission to iterate (loop) over profiles, I think the account needs to have "Manage user profiles" permission. The farm account does NOT automatically have this permission, the SSP service account does (separation of concerns).

Comment: Yes, Web service running in sharepoint environment only. I also remove hack code still it is not working. I just added farm account to Manage User Profiles. Still the same error.